# Manipulating audio files with VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, audio

I've done quite a bit of Googling but I don't think I'm getting the right search terms.

I need to be able to read audio files and manipulate them from within my own program (similar to how Audacity does it).  Now, I'm not asking for something with a thousand effects and such, I just need the minimal as far as audio manipulation for .net goes. I really just need to be able to figure out pitches and frequencies being played at what times and the ability to move them all around.

I'm personally looking for a VB.net answer, however, I am perfectly fine with any .net code!

Comment: If you are referencing a CLS compliant .NET library, it doesn't matter what language it was written in.

Comment: What kind of audio files? Some formats will probably be much easier to work with/find libraries for than others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) library:

> NAudio is an open source .NET audio and MIDI library, containing dozens of useful audio related classes intended to speed development of audio related utilities in .NET. It has been in development since 2001 and has grown to include a wide variety of features. While some parts of the library are relatively new and incomplete, the more mature features have undergone extensive testing and can be quickly used to add audio capabilities to an existing .NET application.